# MongoDB Sort Query in C# .NET Driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, sorting

I've been trying to `Sort` a collection using MongoDB **SortDefinition** but whenever I "sort" the collection via a single sort definition, all I get returned is an empty list. However, when I use more than one sort definitions, it returns values.

```
var TestSort1 = Builders<Scenario>.Sort.Ascending("Name");

        var filtered1 = await _context
            .DbCollection
            .Find(_ => true)
            .Sort(TestSort1)
            .ToListAsync();
```

The code above returns an empty list. However, the code below works fine.

```
var TestSort2 = Builders<Scenario>.Sort.Ascending("Name").Ascending("Owner");

        var filtered2 = await _context
            .DbCollection
            .Find(_ => true)
            .Sort(TestSort2)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Is it possible to use a single **SortDefinition** to sort the collection? Or maybe I am using the **SortDefinition** wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try using the fluent C# syntax for creating aggregation pipelines...

```
    var collection = database.GetCollection<FiltroCond>("dbCENTRAL");

    var filter = Builders<FiltroCond>.Filter.Eq(x => x.PartnerId, cliente) 
        & Builders<FiltroCond>.Filter.Eq(x => x.TP_PESSOA, 3) 
        & Builders<FiltroCond>.Filter.Gte(x => x.FG_ATIVO, true);

    var result = collection.Aggregate().Match(filter)
        .Project(p => new FiltroCond { CD_CLIENTE = p.CD_CLIENTE, ID_CENTRAL = p.ID_CENTRAL, FANTASIA = p.FANTASIA })
        .SortBy(p => p.ID_CENTRAL).ToList();
```

It works fine to me.